# Implementing javascript Object.defineProperties

Tags: javascript, object, properties

Hello I found some difficulties when implementing javascript Object.defineProperties:

```
var book1 = {};
Object.defineProperties(book1, {
_year: {
    value: 2004
},
edition: {
    value: 1
},
year: {
    get : function() {
        return this._year;
    },
    set : function(newValue) {
        if ((newValue - this._year) > 0) {
            this.edition += 1;
        } else if ((newValue - this._year) < 0) {
            this.edition -= 1;
        }
        this._year = newValue;
    }
}
});
book1.year = 2005;
document.write(book1.edition);  //get 1, expect 2
document.write('<br/>');
book1.year = 2006;
document.write(book1.edition); //get 1, expect 3
document.write('<br/>');
```

Browser: Chrome 17.0.963.56

Any answer is welcome. 
Thank you.

Comment: Note that your `_year` property is still public and anyone can write to it (if you fix the `writable` issue Rob flagged up for you). To make a *truly* private `year` that can only be accessed via your accessor functions, use a closure: http://jsbin.com/eziked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify `writable: true` as a [property descriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Difference_with_usual_property_addition_and_default_values) of `_year`. By default, it's not writable, and assigning a value to a non-writable property doesn't have any effect.

I strongly recommend to activate the strict mode, because you will receive an error message when the assignment of a value to a read-only property fails.

```
"use strict"; // <---
Object.defineProperties(book1, {
    _year: {
        value: 2004
        writable: true  /* <-- writable set to true*/
    },
    edition: {
        value: 1,
        writable: true
    },
```

Comment: Thank you, settings writable: true in data properties has solved the problem.